# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState while showing a fragment already added to the fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, illegalstateexception, onsaveinstancestate

I know there are a bunch of issues related to this and I've read a lot of them. That's why I have my code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWrapperFragment = WrapperFragment.newInstance();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.layout_content, mWrapperFragment, WrapperFragment.TAG)
        .hide(mWrapperFragment)
        .commitNow();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mIsInstanceStateSaved = false;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    mIsInstanceStateSaved = true;
}

@Override
public void onWebApplicationReady() {
    if (shouldShowWrapperWebView()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0)
            .show(mWrapperFragment)
            .commitNow();
    }
}

/**
 * Indicates whether the {@code WrapperFragment} instance should be shown or not.
 * <p>
 * This method will return {@code false} in the following scenarios:
 * <ul>
 * <li>The {@code WrapperFragment} is already visible to the user.</li>
 * <li>The {@link #onSaveInstanceState} method has not yet been called.</li>
 * <li>The activity is not in the process of finishing.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @return {@code true} if the {@code WrapperFragment} can be shown, {@code false} otherwise.
 */
private boolean shouldShowWrapperWebView() {
    return !mWrapperFragment.isVisible() && !mIsInstanceStateSaved && !isFinishing();
}
```

One thing important to note here is that `onWebApplicationReady` is a callback that will be invoked by a web application loaded on `WebView` that `WrapperFragment extends WebViewFragment` hosts.

Given my `shouldShowWrapperWebView()`, I don't understand why I'm still getting this exception which is crashing the app for some users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(SourceFile:1832)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(SourceFile:1954)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(SourceFile:1965)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(SourceFile:614)
       at com.companyname.wrapper.WrapperActivity.showWrapperWebView(SourceFile:336)
       at com.companyname.wrapper.WrapperActivity.onWebApplicationReady(SourceFile:197)
       at com.companyname.wrapper.js.NativeApi$1.run(SourceFile:61)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```